# Problema na inserção de registro unique MySQL

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados

Tenho uma tabela que tem um campo unique, foi excluído um registro dessa tabela e agora deseja-se inseri-lo novamente, no entanto o MySQL me gera o erro: "Error Code: 1062. Duplicate entry '' for key ''". Como posso solucionar isso?

**CREATE DA TABELA:**

```
CREATE TABLE `bem` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cpf` varchar(17) NOT NULL,
  ...
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `cpf` (`cpf`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1764 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;
```

**EXEMPLO DE INSERT:**

```
INSERT INTO `bem` (cpf, ...)VALUES ('12312312312', ...);
```

Comment: Coloca create da tabela.

Comment: Poste o `CREATE TABLE`  e também a query de `INSERT` que está fazendo.

Comment: vc tem alguma coluna chamada `excluido` ou `ativo`? pq basicamente o cpf do insert já existe na tabela.

Comment: O registro foi realmente excluído, dando um select nada retorna.

Comment: A exclusão foi física de fato (delete) ? O delete e o select foi feito na mesma seção  usuário ? qual o erro informado ?

Comment: Sim foi delete.

Comment: O erro informado é : "Error Code: 1062. Duplicate entry '12312312312' for key 'cpf_UNIQUE'" . O delete foi feito a mais de um mês.

Comment: Eu faria um dump dessa tabela, criaria uma nova base e testaria novamente.

Comment: Com dump funciona, mas não quero ter que fazer isso toda vez que ocorrer outro erro igual.

Comment: Esse teste é para saber se tabela não está corrompida.

Comment: Meu amigo, melhor passar a expressão `CREATE TABLE` completa. Outra coisa, verifique se, quando você gera o `INSERT` dinamicamente, todos os campos obrigatórios estão realmente sendo populados com valores.

Comment: Sem o código completo fica difícil de ajudar, mas o que você pode fazer é utilizar a condição ON DUPLICATE KEY do mysql, atualizando os valores caso encontre o erro de chave duplicada.

Answer (score 0):

Tenta rodar o reparador de tabelas do MySQL.

Se for uma tabela usando o engine `InnoDb`, basta fazer esse `ALTER TABLE`que a mesma sofrerá um *rebuild*:

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE t1 ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Se for uma `MyISAM`, basta fazeR:

```
mysql> REPAIR TABLE t1;
```

Comment: Teste isso e não resolveu.